folders empty after (find . capcut "*.bak" -type f -delete)
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, and unfortunately all the files in all the folders have been wiped out. I have used this: (find . capcut "*.bak" -type f -delete) to cancel files with a specific name of CapCut, but it has removed all kinds of files in the all memory.
The weird thing is that on the Disk program if I check it shows that the partition is partially full 629 GB — 460 GB free (26.8% full), but there are no files anywhere. What I had it was approximately 50GB so it seems that are still there somewhere. How can I see my files or retrieve them?
Disk 
R'Linux program:

Yes yesterday it was asked and unfortunately no answer was found and after that I have rephrased better, the other post have already been deleted. :-)

You deleted all files in the working directory and it's subdiretories. Take a look at this question how to recover deleted files. Or restore your files from backup.

if everything is deleted how is it possible that there are about 130 gb in use in my HD? I have attached a photo of r-linux (one of the methods or recovering files) in the description

I didn't say everything is deleted, please read carefully. We don't know which directory was the current working directory when you issued that command. The command you provide in your question will delete all files in this directory and it's subdirectories. No doubt about that.

ok,so how can I know the directory? or how can I fix this?

There is no reliable way to find out which directory you emptied. Check your command history (~/.bash_history) for cd-commands you ran before. Check out the link in my comment above. For the future, maintain proper backups, run find without the -delete-action first to see what would happen, deleted files are hard to recover.

yes lesson learned, I've tried to run that but it says 'permission denied' Any solutions?

you might find this LearnLinuxTV video concerning using find helpful
